# Google map shows blank in flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geolocation, google-maps-flutter

can anyone help me please, I'm trying to implement google map in my flutter app, the problem I'm facing is the google map shows bland with google logo only. I have generated the key, inserted plugins but nothing seems to be working out.

I really need help

Comment: Can you show me your code?

Comment: class _MapAppState extends State<MapApp> {
  static const _initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
    target: LatLng(37.773972, -122.431297),
    zoom: 14.0,
  );
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: GoogleMap(
      myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
      zoomControlsEnabled: false,
      initialCameraPosition: _initialCameraPosition,
    ));
  }
}

Comment: @Precious can you add your code to your question please, not as a comment?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your Google maps API key in your AndroidManifest.xml as per the Google maps flutter documentation. Since you said that you have generated the key.

Comment: I added the key but still nothing

Comment: Have you [enabled billing](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/cloud-setup#billing) on the project where you got your API key?